# xajax Javascript component could not be included

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, xajax

I am Facing the following error while using ajax in codeigniter. I have successfully implemented xajax at client side, it it gives the error on admin side.
the admin and client controller  are at controllers directory.

The error is
Error: the xajax Javascript component could not be included. Perhaps the URL is incorrect?
URL: xajax_js/xajax_core.js

please specify the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a recent version of the Apache2 web server installed, and are not using some other web server.  I had exactly this problem and here are my suggestions as they relate to Apache2.

Make sure that you have a proper alias installed for the xajax files in the Apache2 web server.  You should have a .conf file in mods-available, symlinked into mods-enabled, with something very similar to the following:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /xajax/ /var/lib/php5/xajax/
    Alias /xajax_js/ /var/lib/php5/xajax/xajax_js/

    <Directory "/var/lib/php5/xajax">
        Require all granted
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Substitute the appropriate path to your xajax installation in the above.

***In particular***, if you are using Apache 2.4, note that the "Require all granted" directive is now *required* instead of the "Order" and "Allow" directives which accomplished the same thing in Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have the javascript URI set if your installation is in another directory.  For example, mine is in `admin/includes/xajax`, so in Xajax 0.6, I had to do

```
$xajax->configure('javascript URI', 'includes/xajax/');
```